# Angularjs 1.5 component two-way binding using bindings in the child component

Tags: angularjs

I always cannot remember correctly the variables on the left side and right side of '=' in the component bindings and understanding bindings in the component.

Let us just using the following demo to discuss:

[Runable demo in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/toddmotto/sdxuc80o/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=sdxuc80o)

1. In the child component, When can we directly just use `bindings: {obj: '='}` without putting a variable on the right side of '='? Or is it a good practice to not put a variable on the right side of '='? I know that if we do not put a variable on the right side of '=', the variable (`<example obj="parent.someObject">`) in the parent template should be the same as the variable on the left side of '='.
2. If I have `bindings: {obj: '= foo'}`, in the parent template, we need to do `<example foo="parent.someObject">`. So, I always remember in this way, variable on the right side of '=' should be put on the left side of '=' in the parent template. Is this a good way to recite this definition?
3. If I want to have communication (pass data) between parent component and child component. I only know using `bindings` in the child component, is it other ways to do it?
4. I know '=' in the bindings is two-way binding, is it a good practice to always use '=' in the bindings? so I do not need to remember '<', '&', etc. I only know this disadvantage if we do not want child component to affect parent component but we still use '=' two ways binding. Except for this disadvantage, is there any disadvantage if we always use '=' two ways binding?
5. We can see in the parent controller, we passed in

   this.someObject = {
       todd: {
         age: 25,
         location: 'England, UK'
       }
     };

But in the template, why it has double quotes in "todd", "age", "location"? What mechanism adds a double quote?
[image]

Thanks for reading this and explain. I appreciate.